# validate upload files in jQuery-File-Upload blueimp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm use validation in `blueimp jQuery-File-Upload`, but when remove the the file which has the problem still does not able to submit the files.

How to know if there is no validation errors after remove the file/files that have the problem ?

**Javascript**

```
var isError = false;
var uploader = $('#fileUpload');
uploader.fileupload({
    url: ' folder/class/method',
    dataType: 'json',
    sequentialUploads: false,
    autoUpload: false,
    maxFileSize: 1048576 * 10,
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
    previewMaxWidth: 70,
    previewMaxHeight: 50,
    previewCrop: true,
    acceptFileTypes: /(gif|jpe?g|png|zip|7z)$/i,
    maxNumberOfFiles: 3
});

// When add file
uploader.on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    var d = data;
    var fileContainer = $('<div/>').addClass('file');
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        $('<div/>').addClass('preview')/*.append($('<span/>').addClass('icon-file-empty fontSize_30'))*/.appendTo(fileContainer);
        $('<div/>').addClass('name').html(data.files[0].name.substr(0, 25)).appendTo(fileContainer);
        $('<div/>').addClass('size').html(filesize(data.files[0].size)).appendTo(fileContainer);
        $('<div/>').addClass('file_progress_container').append($('<span/>').addClass('progress')).appendTo(fileContainer);
        $("<button/>").addClass('delete_btn').append($('<span/>').addClass('icon-bin')).appendTo(fileContainer).on('click', function (e, data) {
            $(this).parent().slideUp('fast', function () {
                d.context.remove();
            });
        });
    });

    data.context = $(fileContainer).appendTo($('#showFiles_container fieldset'));
    $('#beginUpload').on('click', function () {
        if (isError == false && data.context.is(":visible")) {
            data.submit();
        }
    });

});

uploader.bind('fileuploadprocessfail', function (e, data) {
    data.context.css('opacity', '0.3').append($('<span/>').append(data.files[data.index].error));
    if (data.files.error && data.files[data.index].error) {
        isError = true;
    } else {
        isError = false;
    }

});
```